# Sending mail through C# with gmail is not working after deploying to host

Tags: c#, email, gmail, smtpclient

I am trying to send mail through Gmail. I am sending mail successfully when I am testing on localhost, but this does not work when I upload it to a web host. I am seeing this type of error:

> Request for the permission of type System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 failed.

Whenever I am using port 25 get this type of error below:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Below is my code of send email.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("host@gmail.com","User@gamil.com");

SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");              
mail.Subject = "Any String" 
mail.Body = mailbody;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com","123");               
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Is there any solution?  Please suggest to me!

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? If so what type?

Comment: Request for the permission of type System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 failed.

Comment: Problem is with network credentials, make sure that your password is more complex and add stuff like `@` ... it's gmail security, it won't let you send mail until your password is complex enough

Comment: Try changing `SmtpServer.Port = 587` to `SmtpServer.Port = 25`. 25 is the default port for SMTP and changing it requires elevated permission

Comment: @Veljko89 I think (and certainly hope) OP isn't actually using that password and just put it there as a placeholder

Comment: I hope so too @MindSwipe

Comment: @MindSwipe You are Right.i am actually not use this password.

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958229/send-email-using-gmail-error-the-server-response-was-5-5-1-authentication-req

Comment: @VishalParmar change password, use something more complex, use some online password generator (with special characters, to be at least 10 length) and it will work ... give it a shot

Comment: @Velijko89 I have 14 length password.combination of special characters,alphabet or number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** OP Added extra information crucial to answering this question, but I'm keeping the old answer around as it might still help someone

**New Answer:**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34894275/9363973) StackOverflow question already answered this question

**OldAnswer:**
As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11994125/9363973) StackOverflow answer already answered, you changed the Port on the SMTP Server to `587` instead of its default (`25`) and this requires elevated permissions causing this error change this:

```
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
```

to this:

```
SmtpServer.Port = 25;
```

and it should work

**Note:** When using SSL the port needs to be `443`

Comment: Still is not working. I am use 25 port then i am seeing exception. The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: Thank q sir.suggestion for portnumber

Comment: `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;` wil resolve secure connection error... it happens when your website runs on HTTP and not on HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**  Your code add `SmtpDeliveryFormat.SevenBit`

**Example:**

```
using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
                        Password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"],
                    };
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.SevenBit;
                    smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
                    smtp.Port = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToNcInt();
                    smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace AmazonSESSample
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address. 
        // This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
        String FROM = "a@a.com";
        String FROMNAME = "ABC";

        // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
        // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
        String TO = "a@a.com";

        // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
        String SMTP_USERNAME = "a@a.com";

        // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
        String SMTP_PASSWORD = "ASJKAJSN";

        // (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message.
        // If you comment out this line, you also need to remove or comment out
        // the "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET" header below.
        String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

        // If you're using Amazon SES in a region other than US West (Oregon), 
        // replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP  
        // endpoint in the appropriate AWS Region.
        String HOST = "smtp-relay.sendinblue.com";

        // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We
        // are choosing port 587 because we will use STARTTLS to encrypt
        // the connection.
        int PORT = 587;

        // The subject line of the email
        String SUBJECT =
            "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using C#)";

        // The body of the email
        String BODY =
            "<h1>Amazon SES Test</h1>" +
            "<p>This email was sent through the " +
            "<a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses'>Amazon SES</a> SMTP interface " +
            "using the .NET System.Net.Mail library.</p>";

        // Create and build a new MailMessage object
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.From = new MailAddress(FROM, FROMNAME);
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
        message.Subject = SUBJECT;
        message.Body = BODY;
        // Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
        message.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

        using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
        {
            // Pass SMTP credentials
            client.Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

            // Enable SSL encryption
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            // Try to send the message. Show status in console.
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to send email...");
                client.Send(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}