# Getting error in sending email from Website hosted on Godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail

I have hosted a website from Godaddy hosting in Windows ASP.net and have purchased an email also from there as well.
On that website, there is a ContactUs Page in which any visitor could fill in his details and Submit. 
For this I am internally using my personal gmail id as 'From' and my info email ID as 'To' to send the email.
I am using the sample code they provided on their website as this [link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/send-email-using-systemnetmail-19291?q=%23953&topic=&pg=1&path=).

But I am getting this error:

**An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 72.167.234.197 (72.167.234.197:25), connect error 10060**

On client.Send(message)

This is my web.config entry as per that link:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="personalID@gmail.com">
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And this is my code to send email:

```
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.AppendLine("<h3>New Query Received:</h3>");
        body.AppendLine();
        body.AppendFormat("Name : {0}<br />", txtName.Text);
        body.AppendFormat("Email : {0}<br />", txtEmail.Text);
        body.AppendFormat("Phone : {0}<br />", txtMobile.Text);
        body.AppendFormat("Query : {0}<br />", txtQuery.Text);

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("manish.rnsconsultancy@gmail.com");

        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@rns-consultancy.com"));

        message.Subject = "New Query from Website";
        message.Body = body.ToString();

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Send(message);
```

Can anyone please help me in this matter, I am stuck on this as their customer support doesn't know other than that link.
I tried switching the emails as From and To also, but got the same error.

Comment: Remove the from address from smtp tag in web config ' from="personalID@gmail.com", Then try it.'

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth Thanks for the reply but its not working, giving same error. I changed it to:  <smtp>
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
      </smtp>

Comment: see this  
https://ae.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/Can-t-Get-GoDaddy-Hosting-and-PHPMailer-to-work/td-p/57698

Comment: What error getting ? Port ssl denoted as without ssl and with ssl is 465.

Comment: @MohamedElrashid your link is completely depends on php side.

Answer (score 1):

try this code to send email.

Send email using System.Net.Mail
To send mail using System.Net.Mail, you need to configure your SMTP service in your application's web.config file using these values for mailSettings:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="your email address">
      <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The network rule's value will be used when you instantiate an SmtpClient in your code.

**PS: Please change port 3535 if you have problems with 25**

C# code example
You can then use code similar to this to send email from your application:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("your email address");

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("your recipient"));

message.Subject = "your subject";
message.Body = "content of your email";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: I tried your code earlier too, with 25, I am getting the error in my original question. With port 3535, I am getting error as : "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 72.167.234.197:3535"

Comment: ohh, but you contact GOGADDY Support Team.

Comment: Didnt get any help from them, they only provide the documented solution which is not working in my case. And when I changed the port to 80, it worked on localhost, but gave error on live website with error as "No permission to assign port in web.config"

Comment: For some reason port 25 stopped working without explanation, generating a timeout error . Switching to port 3535 worked well.

Answer (score 0):

after checking you [DNS record](https://dns.google.com/query?name=rns-consultancy.com&type=MX&dnssec=true) i found

```
smtp.asia.secureserver.net
```

Use this code and **Add your password**

```
var message = new MailMessage();

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@rns-consultancy.com"));
message.From = new MailAddress("info@rns-consultancy.com");

message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "Body";

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();



smtpClient.Host = "smtp.asia.secureserver.net";
smtpClient.Port = 25;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 

smtpClient.Credentials =
     new NetworkCredential("info@rns-consultancy.com", "Password");

//smtpClient.Port = 465;
//smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

//smtpClient.Timeout = 10000; 
// don't use 100000 in production it's 2 match 
//, just for testing
smtpClient.Timeout = 100000;

smtpClient.Send(message);
```

refrences

- [Google Public DNS](https://dns.google.com/query?name=rns-consultancy.com&type=MX&dnssec=true)
- [Mail server addresses and ports for Business Email | Workspace Email - GoDaddy Help SG](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/mail-server-addresses-and-ports-for-business-email-24071)
- [Network Tools: DNS,IP,Email](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3arns-consultancy.com&run=toolpage#)
- [Solved: Not able to send email via C#. - GoDaddy Community](https://ae.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/Not-able-to-send-email-via-C/td-p/36339)
- [What type of hosting account do I have? | GoDaddy Help AE](https://ae.godaddy.com/help/what-type-of-hosting-account-do-i-have-6971)
- [c# - SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992851/securityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-net-mail-smtppermi)

Comment: Nop, getting this error by this code: {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}

Comment: @HemantSisodia is info@rns-consultancy.com Assign SMTP relay ? see https://in.godaddy.com/help/assign-smtp-relays-20153

Comment: do still need help ?

Comment: I dont see "Additional Options" in my "GoDaddy Business Email" settings. When I click on "Manage", I only see options to change password, Recheck DNS and Delete Account.

Comment: do you still need help ?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Thanks for your reply. But I used your code and still it is giving me permission error.:  Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Comment: @HemantSisodia SmtpPermission meas you server can't use Port  465 , I just updated the code

Comment: After using Port 25, I am getting this error now: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 182.50.144.66:25
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 182.50.144.66:25

Comment: The code runs fine on my local machine, but gives these errors when I publish my code on the website hosted on godaddy server

Comment: could you please tell me what else I could try?

Comment: Getting the same error with this too: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 182.50.145.3:25

Comment: add Credentials after UseDefaultCredentials

Comment: I tried this too with smtpout.asia.secureserver.net but no success. Do you know anything else?